# Async-await: Does the thread run until my await?

Tags: c#, async-await

I always thought that if I call an async function, the thread starts executing this async function until it sees an await. Instead of waiting idly I thought that it would go up the call stack to see if the caller is not awaiting. If not, it executes the code.

Consider the following (simplified) code:

```
async Task<string> FetchCustomerNameAsync(int customerId)
{
    // check if customerId is positive:
    if (customerId <= 0) throw new ArgumentOutofRangeException(nameof(customerId);

    // fetch the Customer and return the name:
    Customer customer = await FetchCustomerAsync(customerId);
    return customer.Name;
}
```

Now what happens if my async function would call `FetchCustomerNameAsync(+1)` without awaiting:

```
var myTask = FetchCustmerNameAsync(+1);
DoSomethingElse();
string customerName = await myTask;
```

- `FetchCustomerNameAsync`, is called with a parameter value of +1
- `FetchCustomerNameAsync` detects that `customerId` is positive, so no exception
- `FetchCustomerNameAsync` calls `FetchCustomerAsync`
- Somewhere inside `FetchCustomerAsync` is an await. when that happens the thread goes up the call stack until one of the callers is not waiting.
- `FetchCustomerNameAsync` is awaiting, so up the call stack
- my function is not awaiting yet, continue with `DoSomethingElse()`
- my function meets the await.

What I thought, is that before the await in my function is met, the check on the parameter value already has been done.

Therefore the following should lead to an exception before the await:

```
// call with invalid parameter; do not await
var myTask = FetchCustmerNameAsync(-1);      // <-- note the minus 1!
Debug.Assert(false, "Exception expected");
```

I'd think that although I was not awaiting, that the check on parameter value was performed before the `Debug.Assert`.

**Yet, in my program no exception is thrown before the Debug.Assert** Why? What is really happening?

### Addition after comments

Apparently some people didn't want the simplified code, but my original test code. Although I don't think it will help describing the problem, here it is.

[Microsoft about usage of local functions in C# 7](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/whats-new/csharp-7#local-functions).
This article describes that an exception will not be detected before the await (as my question was). This astounded me, because I always thought that the parameter was already checked. So I wrote some test code. (now I know better, thanks to answerers and commentors).

So here is my Non-simplified test code. It compiles, it runs, and it shows the effect. However it does not help describing the question, it only distracts from it. But for those who are still interested after all these warnings:

```
async Task DemoLocalFunctionsInAwaitAsync()
    {
        // using local functions after parameterchecks gives errors immediately

        // No exception before await:
        Task<int> task1 = OldMethodWithoutLocalFunction(null);
        // See? no exception

        // New method: exception even if no await
        try
        {
            Task<int> task2 = NewMethodUsingLocalFunction(null);
            // no await, yet an exception
            Debug.Assert(false, "expected exception");
        }
        catch (ArgumentNullException)
        {
            // this exception is expected
        }

        try
        {
            // await the first task that did not throw an exception: expect the exception
            await task1;
            Debug.Assert(false, "expected exception");
        }
        catch (ArgumentNullException)
        {
            // this exception is expected
        }
    }
```

Below the function as I would normally write it:

```
    async Task<int> OldMethodWithoutLocalFunction(Customer c)
    {
        // this does not throw exception before awaited
        if (c == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(c));
        await Task.CompletedTask;
        return c.CustomerId;
    }
```

This is the function that uses the local function. Almost as described in the Microsoft article mentioned above.

```
    async Task<int> NewMethodUsingLocalFunction(Customer c)
    {
        // this method gives an exception even if not awaited yet
        if (c == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(c));
        return await LocalFetchCustomerIdAsync(c);

        async Task<int> LocalFetchCustomerIdAsync(Customer customer)
        {
            await Task.CompletedTask;
            return customer.CustomerId;
        }
    }
```

If you look closely: this will also not help (and I understand now why, thanks to answerers and commentors).

Comment: I presume you have missed off the `async` on the function?  `async Task<string> FetchCustomerNameAsync(int customerId)` ?

Comment: Your invalid parameter appears to be positive, so not sure why you expect an exception. (Of course, that may just be a transcription error into the question but that's why we much prefer to see *real code* that's been executed and *just* copied into the question)

Comment: oeps, copy-paste error. Corrected

Comment: So, rather than giving us "simplified" code that *isn't* copied & pasted, please give us an [mcve]. Do you know that *the code in this question* demonstrates the issue you're asking about?

Comment: Your exception is stored and will be thrown on the await. What did your debugger tell you?

Comment: Exceptions are stored inside tasks. When you await a task which contains an exception, the exception is thrown at that point. Because you don't await `FetchCustmerNameAsync`, the exception is just sitting inside the task.

Comment: Or the fact that it names a non-existent exception type, has incorrect syntax, and has obviously *not been put in front of a compiler*. That's why I ask.

Comment: Ok, so the parameter is checked, the exception is thrown, but kept inside the task. It only results in an exception in my context when I wait for task completion. Makes sense

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right about that thread executes async function until it sees an await. In fact your `ArgumentOutofRangeException` is thrown by the thread on which you call `FetchCustmerNameAsync`. The reason why you don't get exception even though it is the same thread is because when you use `await` inside a function, a `AsyncStateMachine` is built. It converts all code into state machine, but the important part is how it handles exception. Take a look:

This code:

```
public void M() {

    var t = DoWork(1);

}

public async Task DoWork(int amount)
{
    if(amount == 1)
        throw new ArgumentException();

    await Task.Delay(1);
}
```

Gets converted into (I skipped unimportant parts):

```
private void MoveNext()
{
    int num = <>1__state;
    try
    {
        TaskAwaiter awaiter;
        if (num != 0)
        {
            if (amount == 1)
            {
                throw new ArgumentException();
            }
            awaiter = Task.Delay(1).GetAwaiter();
            if (!awaiter.IsCompleted)
            {
                // Unimportant
            }
        }
        else
        {
            // Unimportant
        }
    }
    catch (Exception exception)
    {
        <>1__state = -2;
        <>t__builder.SetException(exception); // Add exception to the task.
        return;
    }
    <>1__state = -2;
    <>t__builder.SetResult();
}
```

If you follow `<>t__builder.SetException(exception);` (`AsyncMethodBuilder.SetException`), you will find that it eventually calls `task.TrySetException(exception);` which adds the exception to the task's `exceptionHolder`, which can be retrieved with `Task.Exception` property.

Answer (score 2):

## Exceptions only propagates when a task is awaited

You can't handle an exception without awaiting the Task. The Exception(s) only propagate within a Thread/Task. So if you don't await, the Exception just stops the Task. And if the exception is thrown before you await, it will propagate when you actually await.

### Do all the validations before, and then do the asynchronous work.

So, I suggest you to validate before:

```
ValidateId(id); // This will throw synchronously.
Task<Customer> customer = FetchCustomerAsync(id).ConfigureAwait(false);
DoSomethingElse();
return await customer.Name;
```

This is the best way to achieve the parallelism you want.

Comment: Makes sense (as was already one of the comments). Apparently `DoSomethingElse` will be executed even if there is an exception in `FetchCustomerAsync()`. Fair enough, because the programmer indicated that the outcome of `FetchCustomerAsync` does not influence `DoSomethingElse`, otherwise he should have awaited before `DoSomethingElse`

Comment: @HaraldCoppoolse If there's a correct answer, please mark it. If not, clarify what you are asking so we can help you.

Answer (score -1):

A simplified MCVE :

```
    static async Task Main(string[] args)
    {       
        try
        {
          // enable 1 of these calls
            var task = DoSomethingAsync();
          //  var task = DoSomethingTask();

            Console.WriteLine("Still Ok");
            await task;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);                
        }
    }

    private static async Task DoSomethingAsync()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();            
    }

    private static Task DoSomethingTask()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
```

When you call DoSomethingAsync, you will see the "Still Ok" message.

When you call DoSomethingTask, you will get the behaviour you expect: an immediate exception before the WriteLine.